# Why computer thinks that I entered date in MM/dd/yyyy format instead of dd/MM/yyyy

Tags: c#, date, datetime

I have created a simple Console Application which has the below lines of code in its Main method:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse("01/03/2014 00:01:05");
string d = dt.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy");
Console.WriteLine(d);
```

I have not provided any error handling or TryParse method to keep this question simple.

As you can see in the above code I want to Convert the string in DateTime format. Then I change the format of the date and then I print the Output.

Output of the above mentioned program will be **03.01.2014**

Now If I change the date in above code to **25/02/2014**, then I will get an exception **Input String was not in a correct format**.

I just purposely entred the date in dd/MM/yyyy. So, now my question is : how should I tell to the computer that I am willing to enter the date in dd/MM/yyyy and not in MM/dd/yyyy?

Comment: What locale is your computer running in?

Comment: Its running in India. UTC+5:30

Comment: It's obviously a parsing issue; some places write the month first and some write the day first. Provide a globalization setting to indicate what culture you are intending: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kc8s65zs(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Wikipedia *[suggests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_format_by_country)* that an Indian locale should infer a date format of `dd-MM-yyyy`; Are you sure you're not set to a US locale?

Comment: @RowlandShaw Yes I am sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't provide a different culture you use the current culture. Obviously your current cultures date format has the month first, then the day.

You can use `DateTime.ParseExact` with `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("01/03/2014 00:01:05", "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Now `dt.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy")` yields 01.03.2014.

Comment: Sorry, Tim my Computer is running Windows and I always see the time in dd/MM/yyyy format. So, If its CurrentCulture then also I should not get any problems. As well as my TimeZone is UTC+5:30.

Comment: @Vishal in your project, what is the value at runtime if you debug of System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat ?

Comment: @TimSchmelter I accept your argument. This is a fresh new Project, I just created to test DateTimeProblems. Now problem is that If I use ParseExact method as you said, I get the output. As well as if I use CultureInfo.CurrentCulture then also I get same result. But I don't know why am I not getting it using Parse Method. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Vishal: Sorry, i don't know why `DateTime.Parse` doesn't work for you. It should if your current cultures's date-format uses `dd-MM-yyyy`(`/` will be replaced with the actual date separator). So maybe some other code changed the current thread's culture. But without code or context it's impossible to find the reason.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Yes that's possible. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1):

This may be because your system localization of dates must be set to MM/dd/yyyy format. You may try to use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` when you are parsing your date.

Try like this:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("01/03/2014 00:01:05", "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Also check [DateTime.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kc8s65zs(v=vs.110).aspx)

EDIT:

Check the date time setting here:

[image]

Comment: What's curious is that your (twice downvoted) answer is the same as a once upvoted one, ppl vote weirdly at times!

Comment: Okay. You provided a poor quality answer just to make sure you're first after which you added in relevant parts bit by bit while a good answer was already posted. I am particularly annoyed by people trying to game the system instead of focusing on quality. That's why you received my downvote.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel:- Got that and I will keep that in mind in future. Thanks :)